# How to retrieve an actionlink text in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of actionlink in my navbar like this

@Html.ActionLink("Customer Profile", "Index", "Profile")

@Html.ActionLink("Supplier Profile", "Index", "Profile")

@Html.ActionLink("Publisher Profile", "Index", "Profile")

now i need to retrieve the link text in my controller to allocate some value in a property by comparing the value of the link text like this

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        if(linktext=="Customer Profile")
        {
            profile.cust_supply_cat_id = 1;
        }
        else if (linktext == "Supplier Profile")
        {
            profile.cust_supply_cat_id = 2;
        }
        else if (linktext == "Publisher Profile")
        {
            profile.cust_supply_cat_id = 3;
        }

        return View(profile);

    }
```

How can i do it?

or if you get the idea what are the possible ways to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send a value from Html.ActionLink like:-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customer Profile", "Index", "Profile", new { linktext: "Customer Profile", null })
```

then receive the value in controller as a argument to a parameter like:-

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string linktext)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: The url become like this
http://localhost:5295/Navigation?Length=7

and Shows
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Navigation

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

Comment: t works as 
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Publisher Profile", "Index", "Profile", new { linkTest="Something" },null)</li>
 but can u explain what is the mechanism

Comment: I have edited my answer, basically Html.ActionLink is a method and it has different overloaded versions which takes in different parameters. In this overloaded version, the first parameter is the text which will be rendered on the page, second parameter is the action name, third parameter is the name of the controller and after that we are passing an anonymous object with a value which will be appended to the url and used in the action method as an argument

Comment: @RaihanRidoy no problem :) please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to the Index function.
E.g:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id).
```

Then add a parameter value to your ActionLinks.
E.g:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Publisher Profile", "Index", "Profile", new {id = 1}, null)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: The url become like this
http://localhost:5295/Navigation?Length=7

and Shows
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Navigation

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

Comment: it works as 
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Publisher Profile", "Index", "Profile", new { id=3 },null)</li>
but can u explain what is the mechanism

Comment: The mechanism is called 'RouteValues'.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx